# Linux Apache: return random image from request

Tags: image, apache, redirect, random

Any request for a jpg gif or png file that would normally 404 on my server needs to return any random image from a folder on my server.

I do not have any clue how I would begin to look up how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `.htaccess` file with content:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.php
```

then make file `not_found.php` on web root (ex: `/var/www/`) with content:

```
<?php
$files = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
$randomNumber = rand (0, 2);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $files[$randomNumber]; ?>" alt="404" />
```

don't forget to include image file (`1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...`) in the same directory.

I think you will understand if you are pointing your not found file to php file like `not_found.php` above. You can also manipulate those php file as you like.